# calling a function from Angular controller in {{ brackets }}

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Controller:**

```
app.controller("DateExample", function($scope) {
    $scope.date = new Date(Date.now());

    $scope.getName = function(index) {
        return ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"][index];
    }
});
```

**Markup:**

```
<span>{{getName(date.getDay())}}</span>
```

I am assuming you cannot call methods from {{ these brackets }} How do I call my function and pass in a value which is also in my controller scope?

Comment: What you've got there is totally fine. You probably should have tested before asking the question ;)

Comment: Also, `new Date()` is the same as `new Date(Date.now())`

Comment: *"I am assuming..."* - don't assume. Try it.

Comment: Dammit! there was a typo in my code causing it ti fail :-|

Comment: avoid using functions in view like that... digests run many more times than you think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of creating controller functions, just use Angular's [`date` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

Controller

```
$scope.date = new Date();
```

Template

```
<span>{{::date | date: 'EEE'}}</span>
```

Note that I've used one-time-binding to avoid running the filter each digest cycle.

Comment: You don't need one-time binding to make sure that a filter doesn't run on every digest... The filter doesn't run unless the filtered expression value changes.

Comment: @NewDev ah, true. I forgot about scope dirty checking